# Getting started with Hybrid Mobile App Development on Salesforce - Unable to create an app using forcedroid create command

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

While following the 'Get Started With Hybrid Development' trail on TrailHead I am facing problem on step **Create a Hybrid App** -

> C:\Users\anand.gupta>forcedroid create
>   Enter your application type (native, react_native, hybrid_remote, or hybrid_loca
>   l): hybrid_local
>
> Enter your application name: MyTrailHybridApp
>
> Enter the target directory of your app (must be an existing empty folder): Trail
>   HybridApps
>
> Enter the package name for your app (com.mycompany.my_app): com.mytrail.hybrid
>
> **". Should be in the format x[.y[.ignored]]
>   ) is less than the minimum required version (5.4.0).  Please update your version
>    of Cordova.**

I have the latest version of Cordova installed ( Cordova version 6.3.0 ).

Even the shutting off the telemetry isn't helping (As was suggested by some users )

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been reported on github relating to the Cordova v6.3:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1209

Try downgrading to 6.2 for now.